# CakePHP: Load name field of related model on view

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, associations

Guys I have a simple but boring question...
I have the following scenario:

```
Solicitation -> HasMany -> Destiny

Destiny -> BelongsTo -> City
```

My problem is on the view, I want to retrieve the City name instead of the city_id and I can't figure out.

Here is my Result:

```
array (size=12)
  'Solicitation' => 
    array (size=32)
      'id' => string '25' (length=2)
  'Destiny' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'solicitation_id' => string '25' (length=2)
          'city_id' => string '4382' (length=4)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'solicitation_id' => string '25' (length=2)
          'city_id' => string '4350' (length=4)
```

How can I retrieve the city name on the view?

Here's my controller:

```
public function mySolicitations()
    {
        $this->Solicitation->recursive = 1;
        $person_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $conditions = array(
            'Solicitation.created_by' => $person_id
        );

        $this->set(array(
            'data' => $this->paginate('Solicitation', $conditions, array('Solicitation.id' => 'DESC')),
            'title_for_layout' => 'My Solicitations'
        ));
    }
```

Is there a problem with my relation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Change your model recursive value to 2.

   ```
    $this->Solicitation->recursive = 2;
   ```

   The drawback of using this is when you have quite a few associations involved, it'll retrieve a lot of unwanted unnecessary data.

---

2. You can use "Containable" Behavior here.

   ```
    $this->Solicitation->Behaviors->load("Containable");
   ```

And specify the model names that you want to retrieve:

```
     $this->Solicitation->contain(array(
        "Destiny", "Destiny.City"
       )
     );
```

Then add your code:

```
    $conditions = array(
        'Solicitation.created_by' => $person_id
    );

    $this->set(array(
        'data' => $this->paginate('Solicitation', $conditions, array('Solicitation.id' => 'DESC')),
        'title_for_layout' => 'My Solicitations'
    ));
```

If you debug, you'll certainly find the "City" index within each Destiny sub arrays.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD